# Sending mail via Java API: How to send the mail even if attachment fails?

Tags: java

This is my code:

```
try {
    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
    message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
    message.setSubject(messageSubject);
    message.setText(messageBody);

    BodyPart messageBodyPart1 = new MimeBodyPart();
    messageBodyPart1.setText(messageBody);
    MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart2 = new MimeBodyPart();
    String filename = attachment;
    DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
    messageBodyPart2.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
    messageBodyPart2.setFileName(filename);
    Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart1);
    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart2);    
    message.setContent(multipart );

    Transport.send(message);
} catch (MessagingException mex) {
    mex.printStackTrace();
}
```

How can I still send the email even if mail attachment fails for some reason? ATM if attachment fails, the email is not sent, which is bad in my case.
Should I use another try/catch statement and should I have finally as well?
Im new to Java (3-4 weeks)

edit:
Changed my code to this, but didnt work

```
try {
    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
    message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
    message.setSubject(messageSubject);
    message.setText(messageBody);

    try {
        BodyPart messageBodyPart1 = new MimeBodyPart();
        messageBodyPart1.setText(messageBody);
        MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart2 = new MimeBodyPart();
        String filename = attachment;
        DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
        messageBodyPart2.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
        messageBodyPart2.setFileName(filename);
        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart1);
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart2);    
        message.setContent(multipart);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        message.setText(messageBody2);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Transport.send(message);

} catch (MessagingException mex) {
    mex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Why would you *want* to send the email if the attachment doesn't attach?

Comment: Because this email is used to inform our team if a continuous integration test has failed. If the test has failed, we will not deploy on the integration server.

Comment: What stackTrace You are getting after you edited the code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. I would expect to be able to do (pseudo-code follows)

```
try {
   // set up standard message
   try {
     // perform attachment
   }
   catch {
     // perhaps amend your original message to indicate attachment failed
   }
   send();
}
catch {
  // handle a complete failure here...
}
```

although I'd concentrate on *why* the attachment fails. Does that even make sense ?

You may take the approach of building/sending in two different methods, such that you don't have to clean up / modify your message in the face of a failure. That may be a cleaner approach e.g. (pseudo-code again)

```
try {
   sendMessageWithAttachment();
}
catch {
   sendMessageWithoutAttachment();
}
```

Comment: I changed my code, but Im not sure I did it right. Edited my question